# Can't compile the static library project with visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, include, visual-studio-2017, static-libraries

I was trying to build my own static library(.lib) using codes in [this tutorial](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Creating_%26_Linking_Static_Libraries_And_Make_Your_Own_Blueprint_Node_With_VS_2017_%26_UE4#Creating_the_static_library). But first of all, static library project will generate a **stdafx.h**, a **targetver.h** and a **stdafx.cpp** for me automatically, so I have to include stdafx.h in all my source files. But once I did that, the project still refuses to compile because now it thinks that **YJMagic is not a class or namespace name**. Then I checked the project's properties and found out the stdafx.h is already my precompiled header file. So maybe it won't compile because there is a double include problem?

Then because I can't figure out a solution, I did it another way: I create an empty project, use the same source file and header file, then manually change the target extension to .lib, and configuration type to static library(.lib).(in **properties**->**configuration properties**->**general**), then hit build, aaaaaand it works!!!! And I wrote a small test script which proves the lib works fine...SO do I see the static library project wrong? I wonder is there anyone got the same problem or someone who can explain?

For those who don't want to open the link to tuto, the source codes are there below:

```
#pragma once

// YJMagic.h

namespace YJMagic
{
    class YJMagic
    {
    public:
        // Returns a + b
        static double Add(double a, double b);
    };
}


// YJMagic.cpp

#include "YJMagic.h"

#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

namespace YJMagic
{
    double YJMagic::Add(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

### Thanks in advance for your answer! Have a nice day;)

Update with references

- [Headers and includes: why and how](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/#msg49679)
- Youtube: [Making and working with libs in cpp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wt4dxDNmDA8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following [solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bf1b4ebd-a957-4cc3-9ca2-0bae99f41db2/error-c2653-std-is-not-a-class-or-namespace-name-resolved-needs-to-be-more-public?forum=Vsexpressvc) worked for me in VS 2017 C++:
*That's a nasty quirk of the compiler.  When it searches for the precompiled headers, it skips any #includes before `stdafx.h`.  Make it look like this to solve your problem:*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It was really a hidden one XD

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround when you don't want to use stdafx:

Delete the offending include, then go into the properties for the project.

Under **C/C++**

Under **Precompiled Headers**

Set **Precompiled Header** to **Not using Precompiled Header**

That stops it from looking for the precompiled header, and you can move on with your life :)